# NITF Metadata not displaying properly in OSGeo Shell. Works in FWTools

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, osgeo, fwtools, nitf

I'm using gdalinfo in the OSGeo Shell to display information on a directory of NITF's. For the majority of the NITF's, gdalinfo is saying the all the corner coordinates are 0, which is incorrect.

However, when running gdalinfo in FWTools Shell, all NITF's display coordinates properly.

This tells me it's not an issue with the metadata of the NITF's.

Has anyone noticed issues with support for NITF's in OSGeo Shell vs FWTools? It's seems like FWTools maybe reads header info differently then OSGeo Shell?